# How to decode JSON

Tags: c#, json

I have my JSON in the following format:

```
{ "news": 
   [ 
     { "fb": { "message": "try", "user": "789" } },
     { "feed": { "abstract": "cool", "title": "hey" } },
     { "tw": { "tweetid": "984327", "user": "gart"  } },
     { "fb": { "message": "fgt", "user": "690" } },
     { "tw": { "tweetid": "346", "user": "nfgdr" } },
     { "feed": { "abstract": "gredf", "title": "wret" } }
   ] 
}
```

I have replaced double quotes so that it can be stored in a string.

Now when I am trying to deserialize this using:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

jss.Deserialize<XYZType>(data);
```

It is giving the following error:

```
Invalid object passed in, member name expected. (1): {"news":[{"fb":{"message":"try","user":"789"}},{"feed":{"title":"hey","abstract":"cool"}},{"tw":{"tweetid":"984327","user":"gart"}},{"fb":{"message":"fgt","user":"690"}},{"tw":{"tweetid":"346","user":"nfgdr"}},{"feed":{"title":"wret","abstract":"gredf"}}]}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Flexo thanks for this. Any probable solution

Comment: @Jash: It would be hard to know what is failing without knowing the structure of XYZType?

Comment: @Jash to make sure - in your string are there `"` or `&quote`? So is the above code reflecting your situation correctly right now?

Comment: Unless the "news" array is serialized into an **object** array, the fact that the objects in the array are not homogeneous is definitely going to land you into some trouble

Answer (score 3):

I would have a look at [Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) and stop "manually" trying to fix stuff and have the system/library do it for you. Also, the JavaScriptSerializer is kinda wonky...

Answer (score 2):

**CONT**: Unless the "news" array is serialized into an object array, the fact that the objects in the array are not homogeneous is definitely going to land you into some trouble while trying to serialize your JSON into a C# object.

If you have control of the JSON (source), you need to structure it better to make it easy to serialize into a C# object. If you could have the JSON take the structure:

```
{ "news": 
    [ 
        { 
            "fb": { "message": "try", "user": "789" },
            "feed": { "abstract_": "cool", "title": "hey" },
            "tw": { "tweetid": "984327", "user": "gart"  } 
        },
        { 
            "fb": { "message": "fgt", "user": "690" },
            "tw": { "tweetid": "346", "user": "nfgdr" },
            "feed": { "abstract_": "gredf", "title": "wret" }
        }
    ] 
}
```

This kind of structure will easily be deserialized by a type XYZType of the following structure:

```
class XYZType
{
    NewsType[] news { get; set; }

    public class NewsType
    {
        FBType fb { get; set; }
        FeedType feed { get; set; }
        TweetType tw { get; set; }

        public class FBType
        {
            string message { get; set; }
            string user { get; set; }
        }

        public class FeedType
        {
            string title { get; set; }
            string abstract_ { get; set; }
        }

        public class TweetType
        {
            string tweetid { get; set; }
            string user { get; set; }
        }   
    }
}
```

**NOTE**:

1) You cannot have an identifier named "abstract" in C# so I have deliberately changed "abstract" to "abstract_"

2) Having the "container" classes embedded is optional. You can make them "not-embedded"

Comment: 1) Actually: [You can](https://compilify.net/1we) but I do agree it's not desireable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just remove the quotes to store it in a string. Then it's not valid Json! You need to delimit the quote so

```
"{\"news\":[{\"fb\":{\"message\":\"try\",\"user\":\"789\"}},etc."
```

Comment: Correct; apart from the ...use\r"... which is probably a typo and should be ...user\"... Also, as an alternative, have a look at the [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx). This allows you to do: _string x = @"Foo "" bar";_ instead of _string x = "Foo \" bar"_